# Normal block upper triangular matrix proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

Prove that if a block upper triangular matrix is normal then its off-diagonal blocks is zero and each of its diagonal blocks is normal.
This question was asked before, but it got just one answer which contains a mistake(it does not take into consideration the order of multiplication of blocks). A complex square matrix $A$ is normal if it commutes with its conjugate transpose $A^*$( $A$ is normal $<=>$ $A^*A=AA^*$). So let’s say the matrix M is normal and it is block upper triangular, so it looks like this:
$$M = \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ 0 & C \end{pmatrix} $$
$$M^* = \begin{pmatrix} A^* & 0 \\ B^* & C^* \end{pmatrix} $$
We know that $A$ and $C$ are square, and we want to prove that $A$ and $C$ are normal, $B=0$.
If $M$ is normal, doing the block-computations gives us four following equations 1) $AA^* + BB^* = A^*A$,
2) $A^*B=BA^*$,
3) $B^*A=CB^*$,
4) $C^*C+B^*B=CC^*$.

This is as far as I was able to get, have no idea how we can prove that $B=0$ from this.
For context, I have completed a year long course of linear algebra, so I would say I know all the basic characteristics of normal matrices, such as spectral theorem and also some facts about Gram matrix of columns of matrix M(that it is a Hermitian matrix for example) and so on.

Comment: Some effort is needed here What is your definition for normal matrices and what different characterizations do you know about them [e.g. spectral theorem]?

Comment: Added the definition of a normal matrix to the question, spectral theorem is familiar to me

Comment: right now this looks like a low effort post, and is likely to be closed for lack of context.  I once again suggest putting in the original post the different characterizations you already know for normal matrices.  Ref e.g. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960

Comment: does this look better or should I add something else?

Comment: Yes.  It is appreciated.  There's a very easy proof in terms of Schur's Inequality and a somewhat better one in terms of M-invariant subspaces.  I'll give one or both.

Comment: From $C^\ast C+B^\ast B=CC^\ast$, we obtain $\|C\|_F^2+\|B\|_F^2=\operatorname{tr}(C^\ast C+B^\ast B)=\operatorname{tr}(CC^\ast)=\|C^\ast\|_F^2=\|C\|_F^2$. Therefore $\|B\|_F=0$.

Answer (score 0):

*polynomial proof:*
observe that for $k \in \mathbb N$
$M^k = \begin{pmatrix} A^k & * \\ 0 & C^k \end{pmatrix}$ and
$M=UDU^*$, $M^*=UD^*U^*$ for some unitary $U$
This means we can find [e.g. via a Vandermonde matrix or Lagrange interpolation] a polynomial $p$ such that
$p\big(D\big)=D^*\implies  p\big(M\big)= Up\big(D\big)U^* =M^*$
Thus while $M^*$ is block lower triangular, we also know $p\big(M\big)=M^*$ is block upper triangular
$\implies M^*$ is block diagonal, i.e. $B=0$

*more conceptual proof:*
let $A$ be $r\times r$.  What $M = \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ 0 & C \end{pmatrix}$  says is that the first $r$ standard basis vectors generate $W$ an $M$-invariant subspace, i.e. $MW\subseteq W$. Since $M$ is diagonalizable $W$ has a basis given by the eigenvectors of $M$ and these are also eigenvectors of $M^*$ since $M$ is normal. Thus $M^*W\subseteq W$ i.e.
$M^*=\begin{pmatrix} A^* & 0 \\ 0 & C^* \end{pmatrix}$

The key result here is that for a diagonalizable   $M\in \mathbb F^{n\times n}$, then any $M$ invariant subspace $W$ has a basis given by eigenvectors of $M$. *Proof:*
Let $\dim W=r$ and create a basis for $W$. Then using the basis extension algorithm, append eigenvectors of $M$ until we have a basis for $\mathbb F^n$.  Let those $n-r$ eigenvectors generate the image of idempotent (/projection) matrix $P$ and $\ker P =W$.
confirm that $w \in \ker P\implies PMw = MPw$ and $v \in \text{image } P \implies PM v= MPv$. Thus $PM=MP$ and both are diagonalizable so they are simultanesouly diagonalizable and in particular $W=\ker P$ has a basis given by the eigenvectors of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following may be an argument which is roughly of the kind the OP requests: suppose that $T$ is a normal operator on $\mathbb C^n$ which has matrix
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc} A & B\\ 0 & D\end{array} \right)
$$
then we claim that $B=0$ and $A$ and $D$ are normal.

Now the condition that $T^*T = TT^*$ yields the following equations in $A,B$ and $D$.
$$
\begin{split}
AA^*+BB^*&= A^*A, \\
BD^* &= A^*B\\
DB^* &= B^*A\\
DD^* &= B^*B+D^*D
\end{split}
$$
Now $\text{Mat}_n(\mathbb C)$ carries an inner product given by $\langle A,B \rangle = \text{tr}(AB^*) = \text{tr}(B^*A)$. Indeed if $A = (a_{ij})$ and $B = (b_{ij})$ then $\text{tr}(AB^*) = \sum_{i=1}^n (AB^*)_{ii} = \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}\bar{b}_{ij}$, thus the inner product is just what one obtains by identifying $\text{Mat}_n(\mathbb C)$ with $\mathbb C^{n^2}$.

But now the first of the above 4 equations implies that $\text{tr}(AA^*)+ \text{tr}(BB^*) = \text{tr}(A^*A)$. Since $\text{tr}(AA^*) = \text{tr}(A^*A)$, it follows that $\text{tr}(BB^*)=\langle B,B \rangle = 0$, and hence by definiteness, $B=0$. This immediately implies that $AA^*=A^*A$ and $DD^*= D^*D$, that is, $A$ and $D$ are normal matrices.